# Binding values not reflected in the XPS Document

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, printing, xps

I have changed the template (Button) fill color based on the scale value through binding.This binding value not reflected in the XPS Document. Please find the template and XPS Doocument serialization code as below.

Problem:
The binding values (level property) are not reflected.So scaling not changed.Since, i have updated scaley value based on the level value.

```
        Xaml Code : based on the level value fill color will change.

        <Canvas.Clip>
         <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,2.5,100,100">
             <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="{Binding Level}" CenterX="0" CenterY="97.5" />
             </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
         </RectangleGeometry>
       </Canvas.Clip>

        //XPS Document Code.  

        //Set up the WPF Control to be Saved

        Canvas controlToPrint= new Canvas();

        //canv is the instance of my canvas containing button.
        controlToPrint = canv;
        canv = null;

        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

        //Create first page of document
        fixedPage.Children.Add(controlToPrint);
        ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

        var size = fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize;
        pageContent.Measure(size);
        pageContent.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), size));
        pageContent.UpdateLayout();
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

        // Configure save file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "MyReport"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".xps"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "XPS Documents (.xps)|*.xps"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            FixedDocument doc = fixedDoc;
            XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(filename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
            xw.Write(doc);
            xpsd.Close();
        }
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this?

Note:

I could able to achieve this while using triggers.But, i should not supposed to use triggers.

Thanks,

Ranjitha.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I fixed by defining the DataContext before calling InitializeComponent()

```
    public PrintingView(ReportViewModel reportViewModel)
    {
        DataContext = _viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```